# Find Integral $\iint{(x^4-y^4)(e^{xy})dA}$ on D

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Where D is in the first quadrant enclosed by $x^2-y^2=3$, $x^2-y^2=4$, $xy=1$, $xy=3$.

So my issue is more in the first step.  I graphed it and it resembles something I would change to polar coordinates, but it doesn't really seem to work.  I have issues with the change of variables, is there a way that could be used for this example that would work for other examples too?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I used $s=x^2-y^2$ and $t=xy$, does that work?

Comment: Yes this is the right thing to do. Try to change the bounds into your new coordinates and change the integrand as well. The area element should be computed